# How to assign custom usergroup during registration with Joomla 3.x?

Tags: joomla

Context: 
I'm just new to Joomla and I'm developing an (joomla 3.x) application where Organisations can register and set up a group, and 'Citizens' can register as a member of this group. (the solution Groupjive is unfortenately not suitable with respect to my specific design goals). Citizens can be member of one or more groups but can also be no member at all.

My specific development questions:

1. How to assign a new custom user group during registration? E.g., with respect to the standard registration process, where in the Joomla code are users assigned to the user groups, e.g., where in the code are the values saved in the `#_usergroup_map` table? I looked at the `register.php` model and controller files `com_users` but could not find the specific code there
2. If I would develop a plugin for  assigning a new custom user group during registration (I believe that is the best approach?) which plugin method should be used?

Comment: Just to be clear you want front-end users to be able to create a Groups? For security purposes I'm assuming you will want that to be a sub-group of one you've already defined, then you want other users to be able to sign up for those groups from the front-end?

Comment: yes, that is correct.